# Calling a getter from another class in a class

Tags: c++, class, getter

I was wondering how you would call a getter function from another class in another class. For example what I have right now is not working

```
class A{
public:
    friend class B;
std::string getfirst(){ return b.getfirst();}
private:
    B b;
};

class B{
public:
    std::string getfirst(){
        return first_;

    }
private:
    std::string first_;

};
```

How would I fix this so that I can call B's getfirst function?

Comment: This code won't even slightly compile... you have `std::string getfirst(){ std::string getfirst(){`.

Comment: I liked the "slightly compile" part ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need friendship.

What about?

```
class B {
public:
    std::string get_first() const { return first_; }
private:
    std::string first_;
};

class A {
public:
    std::string get_first() const { return b.get_first(); }
private:
    B b;
};
```

Now, class B has a getter for its first and class A has getter that delegates to b member variable.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me a compile error saying that B doesn't have a getfirst member

Comment: Check typing. In my example I named the getter as get_first() instead of getfirst().

Answer (score 0):

```
    class B{
    public:
        std::string getfirst(){
            return first_;
        }
    private:
        std::string first_;
    };

    class A : public B{
       public:
       //class A has derived the "getfirst" from B
       private:
       // add your stuff here
  };
```

did not compile it,but should work fine

Answer (score 0):

The code you have has an error:  `std::string getfirst(){` is repeated twice in `B`, this will cause a compilation error.

Also, you do not need to declare `B` as friend of `A`, as `B` is not trying to access any of `A`'s private members.  Ignore this if you have a larger code where you *do* need the friend declaration.

You need to define class `B` before using using it in `A`.  As `B` does not access `A`, you can just put its definition before `A`'s.

Answer (score 0):

This is really wierd

```
std::string getfirst(){ 
        std::string getfirst(){ 
            return first_;      //cause compilation error
```

It may correct as:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B; // Forward declaration of class B in order for example to compile
class A
{

public:

    string getfirst();
    friend string :: getfirst(); // declaration of global friend
};

class B
{

public:

    friend string :: getfirst(); // declaration of global friend
    friend string A::getfirst();  // declaration of friend from other class
};
```

I am giving skeleton only.

Comment: it didn't compile for me, it says that class B does not have the member getfirst